# How does this JavaScript event function work?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, syntax, dom-events

Please explain to me how this JavaScript row works:

`<a href="javascript:" onclick="document.location='AddItem.aspx?catid=<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>'">[edit items]</a>`

Comment: When you click it - don't you see what's done? How ever is not so good implemented, you need to return false onclick, and use # on the href, and not the javascript:

Comment: what is the meaning of #,i.e href="#"?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. (and return false; on onclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It opens another web page. At least when the server-side script part put in the proper ID.

Note that `<%# Eval("CollectionID")%>` is **not** JavaScript.

The javascript part is just `document.location='string'`.